# Python Selenium not clicking the correct button in a popup modal using CssSelector

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

I am using the selenium webdriver in Python to process through a website, but I am running into an issue with clicking a specific button that shows up in a popup modal. Currently, the behavior seems as though the click is being performed, but appears to be clicking the "No" button instead of "Yes."

Here is the snippet of code I am currently using. The first click will hit an "Apply" button, which then opens a popup confirmation modal that requires the user to select No or Yes to continue with applying the request.

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, xpaths['planRangeApply']).click()
time.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.modal-footer:nth-child(3) > jv-button:nth-child(2)'))).click()
```

For comparison, here is the CSS_SELECTOR for the "No" button:

```
div.modal-footer:nth-child(3) > jv-button:nth-child(1)
```

From what I have researched so far, I am properly waiting for the modal to appear and the proceed to find the `Yes` button element. Am I misunderstanding this process or is my CSS_SELECTOR path simply incorrect? I have tried utilizing XPATH instead of CSS_SELECTOR, but I get the exact same result.

Here is a screenshot of the page inspector with the correct button highlighted:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The *CSS_SELECTOR* is slightly off.

- The *parent* tag is *`<div class="modal-footer">`*
- The desired element is the **second** *`<jv-button>`* child of it's parent.

---

### Solution

The effective *CSS_SELECTOR* would be:

```
div.modal-footer jv-button:nth-child(2)
```

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for pointing out that proper parent-child syntax. However I am still resulting in the same issue as before, where the app acts as if I am hitting the "No" button. I attempted to drill down through the CSS Selector past just the jv-button, but still the same result with that too. Is there something I need to do with the script to have it focus on the modal? While watching the inspector, I noticed it will load an entirely different body inside the html tag.

Comment: _it will load an entirely different body inside the html tag_: You mean different window, then you may need to switch window handles.